# How can i fix Array list cast in java

Tags: java

When I run the following program it throws an error:

> class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.synesisit.biwta.base.payload.VesselInfo
> getVesselInfoByOwnerNid return list

```
  public List<VesselTaxStatusResponse> findPendingTaxByVesselOwnerId(String vesselOwnerNID) {

        List<VesselTaxStatusResponse> vesselTaxStatusResponseList = new ArrayList<>();

        List<VesselInfo> vesselInfoList = getVesselInfoByOwnerNid(vesselOwnerNID);

        System.out.println(vesselInfoList);


        if (vesselInfoList != null) {
            for (VesselInfo v : vesselInfoList) {
                Long vesselId = v.getVesselId();
                VesselTaxStatusResponse vesselTaxStatusResponse = findTaxStatusByVesselId(vesselId);
                vesselTaxStatusResponseList.add(vesselTaxStatusResponse);
            }
        }
        return vesselTaxStatusResponseList;

    }

public List<VesselInfo> getVesselInfoByOwnerNid(String nid) {

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder
            .getContext().getAuthentication();
    String jwt = jwtTokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
    String client_url = AppConstants.GET_VESSEL_BY_OWNER_NID + nid;
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt);
    HttpEntity<String> jwtEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<?> result = restTemplate.exchange(client_url, HttpMethod.GET, jwtEntity, ApiResponse.class);

    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(result.getBody())) {
        ApiResponse apiResponse = (ApiResponse) result.getBody();
        List<VesselInfo> responseData = (List<VesselInfo>) apiResponse.getData();
        return responseData;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: what relation do you see between those two classes?

Comment: Your `getVesselInfoByOwnerNid` method has a bug; it is ignoring a generics warning or engaging in some hackery and has ended up putting a LinkedHashMap instance in your list-of-`VesselInfo` objects. You'd have to paste the code of that method for anybody to be able to tell why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This getVesselInfoByOwnerNid method API request should response list but that API return HapMap
> when I convert HasMap to JSON then it works ok.

```
  public List<VesselTaxStatusResponse> findPendingTaxByVesselOwnerId(String vesselOwnerNID) {

        List<VesselTaxStatusResponse> vesselTaxStatusResponseList = new ArrayList<>();

        List<VesselInfo> vesselInfoList = getVesselInfoByOwnerNid(vesselOwnerNID);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(vesselInfoList);
        Type vesselInfoListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<VesselInfo>>() {}.getType();
        List<VesselInfo> vesselList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, vesselInfoListType);
        if (vesselList != null) {
            for (VesselInfo v : vesselList) {
                Long vesselId = v.getVesselId();
                VesselTaxStatusResponse vesselTaxStatusResponse = findTaxStatusByVesselId(vesselId);
                vesselTaxStatusResponseList.add(vesselTaxStatusResponse);
            }
        }
        return vesselTaxStatusResponseList;

    }


    public List<VesselInfo> getVesselInfoByOwnerNid(String nid) {

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder
                .getContext().getAuthentication();
        String jwt = jwtTokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
        String client_url = AppConstants.GET_VESSEL_BY_OWNER_NID + nid;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt);
        HttpEntity<String> jwtEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<?> result = restTemplate.exchange(client_url, HttpMethod.GET, jwtEntity, ApiResponse.class);

        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(result.getBody())) {
            ApiResponse apiResponse = (ApiResponse) result.getBody();
            List<VesselInfo> responseData = (List<VesselInfo>) apiResponse.getData();

            return responseData;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

is getVesselInfoByOwnerNid returning a HashMap?

So if your question is how to convert a hashmap to a pojo then one fine way is by using Jackson:
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // jackson's objectmapper
final VesselInfo vesselInfo = mapper.convertValue(map, VesselInfo.class);

Comment: getVesselInfoByOwnerNid return a list